# How to setup SpagoBI on AWS Instance

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spagobi

I want to setup SpagoBI on AWS (Amazon Web services) EC2 instance. I have downloaded the all in one package and moved it to AWS. I ran the startup script. I have done the same steps on my local machine and it is working just fine.

On AWS EC2 I have opened port 8080 for tomcat and 80 for http. I can't access software.

Any idea on how can I fix the issue, will highly appreciated!

Comment: I have re-created instance and allowed all trafic, I can access tomcat main page myip:8080 but when I do myip:8080/SpagoBI it throws 404 error.

Comment: I am running micro instance and with high resources requirement I am doubtful if it is this micro instance which has not enough resources to meet Spago requirement

Answer (score 0):

Could be this?
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=312167#312167

> initially looks like iptables is running on your instance, my checks show filtered ports, you will need to add a rule to allow port 8080, or disable the firewall on the instance itself.
>
> You can verify this by running as root "service iptables stop" and then see if you can connect on port 8080.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can access every thing in webapps forlder. I have created a test file under a TestDir and access it myip:8080/TestDir/test.html and it is working. If I create the same file under SpagoBI it is showing 404 page. I don't know what's going on? -- @Mcx

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS but have you tried to chmod the files of SpagoBI?

Comment: Yes, I have changed ownership and permissions. I think it is resource issue. Micro instance doesn't support that much processing

Answer (score 0):

Have you set JAVA_HOME and path? Unless these are set correctly Tomcat will 404 when trying to start SpagoBI. See here: http://www.chuckboecking.com/blog/bid/290761/SpagoBI-Installation-on-Ubuntu-Linux-Business-Intelligence-for-ERP